# How to change order of creation of processes?

Tags: c, linux, process

I have to make a tree of processes like in this image:
[image]

I have managed to create such a tree, but with a minor difference. P4 is actually P3, and P3 is P4. I have created them in order, because i can't think of a way of "attaching" P4 to P1, and P3 to P2. 
 This is what I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "a2_helper.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    printf("Main pid is %d\n", getpid());

    pid_t pid1[2];
    pid_t pid2[4];
    pid_t pid3a, pid3b;

    //FIRST LAYER
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        pid1[i] = fork();

        if(pid1[i] == 0){
            printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

            //SECOND LAYER
            if ( i == 0){
                for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                    pid2[j] = fork();

                    if (pid2[j] == 0){
                        printf("\t[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

                        //THIRD LAYER
                        if (j == 1){
                            pid3a = fork();

                            if (pid3a == 0){
                                printf("\t\t[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                exit(0);
                            }

                            waitpid(pid3a, NULL, 0);
                        }


                        if (j == 2){
                            pid3b = fork();

                            if (pid3b == 0){
                                printf("\t\t[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                                exit(0);
                            }

                            waitpid(pid3b, NULL, 0);
                        }
                        //END THIRD LAYER


                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            //END SECOND LAYER

                for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    waitpid(pid2[j], NULL, 0);
            }


            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        waitpid(pid1[i], NULL, 0);
    //END FIRST LAYER

    return 0;
}
```

What can I change in order to achieve that?

Comment: You are going to need some kind of interprocess synchronization, So that P3 can signal its creation to P1.

Comment: The best  way to do this really depends on the constraints you have. Could you clarify if this is homework, and if there are any apis/abis you are not allowed to use? If everything is fair game I would probably use lock files to achieve the needed sychronization

Comment: @PiRocks Yes this is homework. The only things i'm not allowed to use (as written in the task) are sleep, usleep and pthread_atfork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better for fork one fewer times than the paths you need. Look at the following code based on the graph (without P3 and P4 switched)

```
void doP1(){
  if(fork())
    doP2();
  else
    doP4();
}

void doP2(){
  if(fork())
    doP3();
  else if(fork())
    doP5();
  else if(fork())
    doP6();
  else
    doP7();
}

void doP3(){
  return;
}

void doP4(){
  return;
}

void doP5(){
  doP8();
}

void doP6(){
  doP9();
}

void doP7(){
  return;
}

void doP8(){
  return;
}

void doP9(){
  return;
}

int main(){
  doP1();
}
```

I separated every node of the tree into its own function which do nothing but fork in the way the graph shows.

When a data-path splits into two, you don't need to create two child threads, you just need to create one. The parent goes one way, and the child goes another.

i.e. P1 should only call fork once, P2 should only call fork three times, P5 and P6 shouldn't call fork at all

I hope that answers your question!

Comment: Shouldn't we call wait/waitpid for those processes?

Comment: It’s not explicitly necessary unless for some reason you want one of the processes to wait for all of the others, but that’s a matter of what you’re trying to do and not a matter of good code.